# How to create package in python 3.5.1?

Tags: python-3.x, package

I have tried to create a package using python  3.5.1 , but got the error when i import the package.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "Pack.py", line 2, in 
>       import Com
>     File "C:\Users\admin\Document\Python\packages\Com__init__.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from Algebra import *
>   ImportError: No module named 'Algebra'

Answer (score 0):

To import a package you created named Algebra, your folder structure should look similar to this:

```
C:\Users\admin\Document\Python\packages\
     Com__init__.py
     Algebra\
         __init__.py
         .
         .
         .
```

Alternatively, you can put the Algebra packages parent directory on python's sys.path.

You'll likely run into another issue once you resolve this, which is you cannot import * from the Algebra package without specifying the **all** trait in Algebra's **init**.py file. Specifying this done like the following, but replacing the values of the list with your module names:

```
__all__=['add', 'subtract', 'multiply']
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Thanks for your solution.